# Poisson Distribution vs Poisson Process

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I need to understand the relation between both these concepts with an example. I have an good understanding of **Poisson distribution** and it's applications. But I am having difficulties linking it to **Poisson Process**.